# Hypothesis testing of linear regression model with variable and slope dummy variable

Tags: statistics, regression, hypothesis-testing, slope

> A researcher wants to explore how people perceive distances in
>   comparison to the actual distance, and see how the presence of contact
>   lenses/no contact lenses affected their performances. The following
>   model was created, where z=1 with contact lenses and z=0 without:
>
> ŷ = [1.05 + (z)(0.21)] * x
>
> The standard errors for the estimated coefficients are 0.357 and
>   0.032, respectively.
>
> Using this model, test the hypothesis that subjects who wear contact
>   lenses would overestimate the distance between the objects.

I know I have to test for null hypothesis: slope = 1 and alternate hypothesis: slope < 1, but I don't know how to set this up with a variable and a slope dummy variable as well, and also take into account the standard errors of both of the coefficients. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

In case with subjects wearing contact lenses we have the following linear regression:
Estimated distance ŷ = 1.26x
Real distance y = 1.26x + e = αx +e, where e is an error. Ee = 0.357.

According to the characteristics of classic regression model, you can use Fisher's statistic to find the confidence interval of the coefficient α of your regression. According to the null hypothesis, α ∈ [1;+∞] with confidence level 100%:
$\frac{(α-α_{estimated})^T X^T X(α-α_{estimated})}{(pσ^2 )} \sim F(p,N-p)$

So, in this case count:
$\frac{(α-α_{estimated})^T X^T X(α-α_{estimated})}{(pσ^2 )} < F_{100}(p,N-p)$

And you'll find the confidence interval of "with lenses distance overestimation" (let it be ${p_1}$). Then find the confidence interval of "with lenses distance underestimation" (let it be ${p_2}$). The probability of your null hypothesis will be fraction: $\frac{p_1}{p_1+p_2}$.